# Talking between classes in Java?

Tags: java, android, class, static

I am creating a UDP messaging system for Android application. 
For that I have created a seperate class with sending, receiving, parsing threads.
The class has to be instanciated only one - ie. only one UDP server!

Now, in Android you have multiple activities in your design which are basically different classes.
I would like to use my UDP communication iterface from those different classes.
But currently UDP CI is instanciated once in the main class. Therefor I cannot access the object from different classes.
Moreover, the CI parse module will have to change settings/UI/... of the whole app depending on the message.

Therefore:

1. Do I need to have instantiation at all if I do not need more than 1 object?
2. Is it a good choice to have everything in the class static?
3. At some point I will need to talk the other way round (obj->main). Should I use callbacks or just pass necessary resources from main to the CI and do things with them in CI?

I hope I described the problem clear enough. Please ask me if any questions arise.

Answer (score 2):

Either store it in Application Context (which is a singleton).
Or do the connection in Service and let each Activity retrieve data if they want.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like that your different classes need an instance of Or formally speaking have a dependency on `UDP Cl`. To address this, we have two options -

- use a dependency injection framework e.g. [guice](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/) to inject such dependencies automatically in different classes
- Old school way - Create a [singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) for `UDP Cl` and all the classes which need UDP Cl can do something like `UDBCl.getInstance()` to get instance of `UDP Cl`

I personally prefer method 1 because that is unit test friendly. Method 2 will be quicker to solve your problem

Comment: Could you please what is dependency a injective framework and how does it work? Any short example?

Comment: Please take a look at http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/Motivation (its gives a great background on how dependency injection helps and how to use it)

Answer (score 0):

Create an instance of the first class in the second class..
Also, you can use bundles to transfer data between classes.

Comment: Data must be serializable for bundles. And I need to minimize object instantiation to minimize memory usage.